# Cannot found Debian Jessie video driver for Dell 3620

Tags: video, debian, driver

I can't find the  Debian Jessie video driver for the Dell workstation Precision Tower 3620.

The SO runs in emulation hardware mode. The graphic card is an Intel Device 5912.

Answer (score 0):

Do a System update with Debian Jessie Non-Free Packages that work for me

1.Edit sources list

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

2.Now simply edit with what you don`t have with sources.list

> deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
>   deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
>   non-free
>
> deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib
>   non-free
>  deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates
>   main contrib non-free
>
> deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
>   deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
>   non-free

3.Update your System

```
sudo apt-get update
```